# How do I implement with Qt5 a simple QML WebView that works on both desktop and mobile?

Tags: android, qt, qml

I am using Qt5.5.1 and wish to use the following QML code

```
Item {
     WebView {
        id: webView
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "qrc:/resources/assets/help.html"
    }
}
```

targeting Windows desktop, I can
import QtWebkit 3.0

targeting android, I can
import QtWebView 1.0

I cannot find a single solution for both platforms - and the docs imply but never quite claim that it is possible.

Comment: Your findings are correct. WebView is currently aimed at mobile platforms though it does work on Mac OS X as well. You have to understand that WebView uses the platform's native web browsing engine, which in the case of Windows would be Internet Explorer -- this would be a significant challenge to support particularly when you consider that Qt runs on versions of Windows that shipped with IE6.